# Script or api to provide the ami-id of the latest amazon-ecs-optimized image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I ran into a requirement where I need get the EC2 ami id of the latest amazon-ecs-optimized image of a specific region. Is there any script or api that is available to pick the ami-id, that they provide while creating a new cluster?

[image: Create Cluster page in AWS Console]

So that once they update the console with the latest ami, I need not update my scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner to get only AMI ID to be used in scripts :

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux/recommended/image_id --region us-east-1 --query 'Parameters[0].Value'
```

Answer (score 2):

One more that purely uses the AWS CLI, since all of the previous examples rely on *jq* and/or pipes. Largely taken from Jason Haines' comment [here](https://recursive.cloud/blog/latest-amazon-ami/).

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner amazon --filters 'Name=name,Values=amzn-ami-????.??.?-amazon-ecs-optimized'  'Name=state,Values=available' --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate) | [-1].ImageId' --output text
```

Answer (score 2):

combining the answer from @romaninsh and @Derek

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux/recommended | \
    jq -r .Parameters[].Value | jq -r .image_id
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) to get the ami-id. The api `describe-images` describes images that are available to you. It is found that the owner id for amazon-ecs-optimized images is `591542846629`.

The following script returns the latest amazon-ecs-optimized image id in the region `ap-northeast-1`.

```
name=$(aws --region ap-northeast-1 ec2 describe-images \
     --owners 591542846629| awk -F ': ' '/"Name"/ { print $2 | "sort" }' \
     | tr -d '",' | grep -v rc |tail -1)

ami_id=$(aws --region ap-northeast-1 ec2 describe-images --owners 591542846629 \
        --filters Name=name,Values="$name" \
    | awk -F ': ' '/"ImageId"/ { print $2 }' | tr -d '",')

echo $ami_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual) installed making searching and sorting easier and more reliable:

```
aws --region ap-northeast-1 ec2 describe-images \
    --owners 591542846629 | \
    jq '.Images[] | {Name, ImageId} | select(.Name | contains("amazon-ecs-optimized") )' | \
    jq -s 'sort_by(.Name) | reverse | .[0].ImageId' -r
```

I'm also using basic name matching in case this owner adds more image types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be done using boto3

```
from operator import itemgetter
# ECS Optimized AMI to use, different per region. ID changes when an updated AMI is released.
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html
AMI_NAME = 'amzn-ami-????.??.?-amazon-ecs-optimized'

session = boto3.Session()
ec2_client = self.session.client('ec2', region_name='ca-central-1')

ecs_amis = ec2_client.describe_images(
    Filters=[
        {'Name': 'name', 'Values': [AMI_NAME, ]},
        {'Name': 'state', 'Values': ['available', ]}
    ]
)
ecs_amis = ecs_amis.get('Images')
ecs_amis = sorted(ecs_amis, key=itemgetter('CreationDate'), reverse=True)
ami_id = ecs_amis[0]['ImageId']
```

And `ami_id` now contains the latest ami as per CreationDate. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to print out all of the AMIs with their metadata and dates, and then choose. AWS CLI limits how many AMIs are returned.

Here's mine, it's similar to above, but with some filters, and also I substitute a few options interchangeably.

```
# Owners
owners=amazon
owners=aws-marketplace
owners=591542846629  # AMZN ECS
owners=microsoft

# AMI Regions
region=us-west-2
region=eu-central-1

# Amazon AMI - ECS
owners=591542846629
type="amazon-ecs-optimized"
aws ec2 describe-images \
 --region ${region} \
 --filters "Name=virtualization-type,Values=hvm" "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" \
 --owners "${owners}" | jq -r '.Images[] | "\(.CreationDate) \(.Name) \(.ImageId)"' | grep "${type}" | sort -r | head
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done via the SSM Parameter Store API

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/amazon-ecs-provides-ecs-optimized-ami-metadata-via-ssm-parameter/

For eg:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux/recommended
```

Answer (score 0):

This one liner prints out just the latest ECS optimised AMI ID for the specified region.

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux/recommended --query "Parameters[].Value" --output text --region us-west-1 | jq -r '.image_id'
```